# clearRect() does not seem to be working during the animation while using setInterval

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to get the red part circles to rotate around the black circle but when they start spinning they do not seem to be clearing and it just draws a red circle around the black one. Is there any way that I can fix this?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var Spin = 0;
var spinred = window.setInterval(MiddleCircles, 10);

function MiddleCircles(){

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(325, 325, 51, Spin, Spin+0.5*Math.PI);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.lineWidth = "10";
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(325, 325, 51, Spin + 1*Math.PI, Spin + 1.5*Math.PI);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.lineWidth = "10";
    ctx.stroke();

    Spin += 0.01;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(325, 325, 50, 0, 360);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    console.log();
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is `myCanvas`? You probably meant `c`.

Comment: Simply don't call the last `stroke()`, it's the one of the black circle, but still is red 10px and will cover the first two arcs. (there would be a lot of things to say about your code, but your question basically falls into the "typo" case.)

Comment: Thank you Kaiido This helped and I ggorlen myCanvas is the canvas id, sorry probably should have included the HTML code.